# Responsive table using table layout

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-tables

I've been trying to figure out why my table is not displaying correctly on my screen when its at 600px. I tried it on codepen and its working okay there must be something stopping it from rendering properly on small screen.

([Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwEjvj))

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    .sample{
        background:blue;
    }

    table {
      border: 0;

    }

    table thead {
      display: none;
    }

    table tr {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
        width:100%;
    }

    table td {
      display: block;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 13px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
        width:100%;
    }

    table td:last-child {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    table td:before {
      content: attr(data-label);
      float: left;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

This is what I get on my web browser at 600px.

[image]

Comment: well if you see the codepen demo and resize it to 600px it should stack up. The image above is at 600px but its not stacked.

Comment: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @MarcAudet I'm testing it on Chrome

Comment: I copied your HTML/CSS into jsfiddle and it works as expected, both in FF and Chrome.  When you built your demo page, is there some other media query that may be conflicting?

Comment: @MarcAudet Right I just tried it on FF and its working as expected :/ its so strange. That's the only media query I have in my css.

Comment: It looks fine on chrome at 600px to me.  Could you have something cached?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure about when the problem occurs. Are you saying that it works fine in the codepen, but it doesn't on your real site?

Comment: Table is still not rendering properly on Chrome at 640px but it seems to be working fine on FF and IE.

Comment: Nvm seems like the css wasn't loading properly.